# SearchAlterationOptions in a Microsoft Graph Search Request not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-search-api

I'm trying to add logic to my c# function app that does something similar to this test query I tried in Graph Explorer:

[image]

This is the response I get back (notice that it automatically fixed my typo and ran the search)

[image]

I'm trying to do this programmatically in c# but it doesn't correct my spelling.  This is what my c# code looks like in part:

```
         var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody
            {
                Requests = new List<SearchRequest>
                    {
                        new SearchRequest
                        {
                            EntityTypes = new List<EntityType?>
                            {
                                EntityType.DriveItem,
                            },
                            Query = new SearchQuery
                            {
                                QueryString = this.searchQuery,
                            },
                            Fields = new List<string>
                            {
                                "listId",
                                "author",
                                "title",
                            },
                            QueryAlterationOptions = new SearchAlterationOptions
                            {
                                EnableSuggestion = true,
                                EnableModification = true,
                            },
                            Region ="US"
                        },
                    },
            };

            var result = await graphClient.Search.Query.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

This is a screenshot of what I get back when I send this query to my app via postman:

[image]

I get an error that looks like this:

[image]

EDIT 1

Trying "NAM" for the region gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to specify a region at all? In your graph explorer request screenshot it is also not specified and it seems to return something meaningful. Maybe open dev tools and check within the network tab what's really on the wire. Maybe there is some additional request header or similar that's missing in the SDK call.

Comment: Do you use the same token in SDK and Graph explorer? Or at least the same user? Or do you use in your SDK an app token, while in Graph explorer a user token is in place?

Comment: Good question, @Oliver.  So in my demo app i'm using an app registration.  but in graph, i've authenticated as myself - as a user.  in the app, it forces me to specify a region.  I can't run the code without it.

Comment: What i've noticed is that in Graph Explorer version 1, the typing mistakes are auto corrected.  But in code, using the same version of the API, they do not auto correct.  Also, no matter what search I execute in code, I always have to have Region =US in order for anything to work.  Otherwise, I get the error saying that I'm missing the region value.  The difference between my code / project and Graph Explorer, is as @Oliver aptly pointed out, I'm using an app registration in my code vs. my user credentials in graph

Comment: While this won't help you to solve this issue, I would guess if you use a user token in your code you  won't need to specifiy a region and the answer would be the same as in the graph explorer. I think to solve the issue and get the expected behaviour also with an app token you'll have to open a technical support request in the azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the value `US` of the `region` property is not correct. Possible values for the region property are:

| Code | Geo location |
| --- | --- |
| APC | Macro Region Geography 2 - Asia-Pacific |
| AUS | Australia |
| BRA | Brazil |
| CAN | Canada |
| EUR | Macro Region Geography 1 - EMEA |
| FRA | France |
| DEU | Germany |
| IND | India |
| JPN | Japan |
| KOR | Korea |
| NAM | Macro Region Geography 3 - Americas |
| NOR | Norway |
| QAT | Qatar |
| POL | Poland |
| ZAF | South Africa |
| SWE | Sweden |
| CHE | Switzerland |
| ARE | United Arab Emirates |
| GBR | United Kingdom |

Try to use one of the value above

```
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody
        {
            Requests = new List<SearchRequest>
                {
                    new SearchRequest
                    {
                        EntityTypes = new List<EntityType?>
                        {
                            EntityType.DriveItem,
                        },
                        Query = new SearchQuery
                        {
                            QueryString = this.searchQuery,
                        },
                        Fields = new List<string>
                        {
                            "listId",
                            "author",
                            "title",
                        },
                        QueryAlterationOptions = new SearchAlterationOptions
                        {
                            EnableSuggestion = true,
                            EnableModification = true,
                        },
                        Region ="NAM"
                    },
                },
        };

        var result = await graphClient.Search.Query.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: ah ok I'll give this a try.  but can you tell me where you got this list from?  maybe a link to a ms doc?  please and thanks

Comment: @dot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/multi-geo-ediscovery-configuration?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: please see EDIT 1.  It's actually saying the only valid region is US.